# Simple boolean test not working

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, boolean-logic

Hi i have a problem i want to test if my string is not empty and not equals to string1 i wann do something but it do not works.

my code:

```
 NSUserDefaults *namePrefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 NSString *savedName = [namePrefs stringForKey:@"myKey"];

if ((savedName != nil)&&([savedName isEqualToString:@"string1"])){ //

        [self myFunction];

    }
```

it do not enters when the savedName is nil it is ok

it enters when the value of it is not nil and not string1 it is also ok

but it enters when savedName is string1, WHY?

thanks for any help bye

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes it will enter if savedname =string1
then it will enter in the block because it is satifing ur conditon.

savedname !=nil true

savedname ==string1 true

then why should not it  enter in the block. it will enter bcoz it satisfying ur condition.

Comment: sorry (![savedName isEqualToString:@"string1"])  i forgot "!"

Answer (score 5):

You’re simply missing the “not” in the conditional:

```
(savedName != nil) && ([savedName isEqualToString:@"string1"])
```

This will be true when `savedName` is not `nil` and equals given string. You want this instead:

```
(savedName != nil) && (![savedName isEqualToString:@"string1"])
```

Also note that you can drop the first part, since messages sent to `nil` objects return `NO`:

```
![nil isEqualToString:@"string1"] ≈ !NO ≈ YES
```

Therefore, a `nil` string is considered different from `@"string1"`. Sounds logical.

Answer (score 4):

Because you told it to here:

```
if ((savedName != nil)&&([savedName isEqualToString:@"string1"])){
```

change to:

```
if ((savedName != nil)&&(![savedName isEqualToString:@"string1"])){ //
```